# Get type of Django form widget from within template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I'm iterating through the fields of a form and for certain fields I want a slightly different layout, requiring altered HTML.

To do this accurately, I just need to know the widget type. Its class name or something similar. In standard python, this is easy! `field.field.widget.__class__.__name__`

Unfortunately, you're not allowed access to underscore variables in templates. **Great!**

You *can* test `field.field.widget.input_type` but this only works for text/password `<input ../>` types. I need more resolution that that.

To me, however difficult it might look, it makes most sense to do this at template level. I've outsourced the bit of code that handles HTML for fields to a separate template that gets included in the field-loop. This means it is consistent across `ModelForm`s and standard `Form`s (something that wouldn't be true if I wrote an intermediary Form class).

If you can see a universal approach that doesn't require me to edit 20-odd forms, let me know too!

Comment: Relevant bug report or feature request: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13009

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of Django 1.11, you can just use `widget.input_type`. Example:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"
           id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"
           name="{{ field.html_name }}"
           placeholder="{{ field.label }}"
           maxlength="{{ field.field.max_length }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The only exception I have found to this is the Textarea widget which as far as I can tell does not have the ```input_type``` property

Comment: I have created a subclass of the ```forms.Textarea``` and I've added the ```input_type = "textarea"```.

Answer (score 45):

Making a template tag might work? Something like `field.field.widget|widget_type`

Edit from Oli: Good point! I just wrote a filter:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter('klass')
def klass(ob):
    return ob.__class__.__name__
```

And now `{{ object|klass }}` renders correctly. Now I've just got to figure out how to use that inside a template's `if` statement.

Edit from Oli #2: I needed to use the result of that in an if statetement in-template, so I just shifted all that logic into the templatetag. Magic. Thanks for poking me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Regarding Edit #2 - with the enhanced `if tags` in Django 1.2, you can do these widget type comparisons right in the template. I posted an example as a separate answer.

Comment: Another nice filter to add (if non-Python people will be handling your templates) is something like this, for your most-used cases:
`def is_checkboxes(form_field_obj):
    return (form_field_obj.__class__.__name__ == "CheckboxSelectMultiple")` ... then you can do `{% if field|is_checkboxes %}` and people will not freak out (...no returns)

Comment: Correction of the function defined in my last comment: `def is_checkboxes(form_field_obj): return (form_field_obj.field.widget.__class__.__name__ == "CheckboxSelectMultiple")`

Answer (score 37):

Following up on the accepted answer - the enhanced `if tag` in Django 1.2 allows you to use filters in `if tag` comparisons. So you could now do your custom html/logic in the template like so:

```
<ul>
{% for field in form.fields %}
  <li>
    {% if field.field.widget|klass == "Textarea" %}
    <!-- do something special for Textarea -->
    <h2>Text Areas are Special </h2>
    {% else %}      
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {{ field }}
    {% endif %}

  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of *field.field.widget*, as opposed to just using *field.widget*?

Comment: @Wipqozn in my experience `field.widget` often produces nothing - I am not sure about this, but maybe it is only set if you set it manually. `field.field.widget` works.

Comment: Look at the `field.field` information at the end of [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) in the docs

Answer (score 21):

Following the answer from Oli and rinti: I used this one and I think it is a bit simpler:

template code: `{{ field|fieldtype }}`

filter code:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter('fieldtype')
def fieldtype(field):
    return field.field.widget.__class__.__name__
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps worth pointing out to contemporary readers that [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) provides `field_type` and `widget_type` template filters for this purpose, returning the respective class names in lowercase. In the example below I also show the output of the `input_type` property on the field widget (since Django 1.11), which may also be useful.

`forms.py`:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        required=True,
        label='Your name'
    )
```

`template.html`:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
{{ field.label }}
{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}
{{ field|field_type }}
{{ field|widget_type }})
{% endfor %}
```

**Result:**

```
Your name
text
charfield
textinput
```

Between these various options you should be able to find the right property to target for just about any use-case. If you need to capture the output of one of these filters for use in `if` statements, you can use the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can make every view that manages forms inherit from a custom generic view where you load into the context the metadata that you need in the templates. The generic form view should include something like this:

```
class CustomUpdateView(UpdateView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       ...
       for f, value in context["form"].fields.items():
          context["form"].fields[f].type = self.model._meta.get_field(f).get_internal_type()
       ...
       return context
```

In the template you can access these custom properties through field.field:

```
{% if field.field.type == 'BooleanField' %}
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     ...
     </div>
{% endif %}
```

By using the debugger of PyCharm or Visual Studio Code you can see all the available metadata, if you need something else besides the field type.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here whose purpose is to customise widget style according to its type, based on @oli answer great idea, I decided to set the mapping directly in the template filter, and return the corresponding classes directly. This avoids messing with `{% if %}` statements in the template.

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

BASIC_INPUT = "border border-indigo-300 px-2.5 py-1.5 rounded-md focus:outline-none"

mapping = {
    "Select": BASIC_INPUT,
    "TextInput": BASIC_INPUT,
    "EmailInput": BASIC_INPUT,
    "RegionalPhoneNumberWidget": BASIC_INPUT,
    "ModelSelect2": "",  # let the default markup
}


@register.filter("get_field_classes")
def get_field_classes(field):
    widget_class_name = field.field.widget.__class__.__name__
    try:
        return mapping[widget_class_name]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(f"Classes related to {widget_class_name} are not defined yet")
```

Then in your default form template (e.g: `django/forms/default.html`), when browsing fields, with the help of [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) package:

```html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load get_field_classes %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}

  {# .... #}

  <div>
    {% with field_classes=field|get_field_classes %}
        {{ field|add_class:field_classes }}
    {% endwith %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```