# Django - Render the <label> of a single form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm selectively rendering fields on a form.

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.ChoiceField(label='Some Foo', ...)
    bar = forms.BooleanField(label='Some Bar', ...)
    ...
```

I've got a custom tag that, based on some other logic, lets me iterate over the fields of the form that I need using the `FIELD` context variable in the tag:

```
{% fieldsineed %}
  {% if FIELD.field.widget|klass == "CheckboxInput" %}
    <li>{{ FIELD }} {{ FIELD.field.label }}</li>
  {% else %}
    <li>{{ FIELD.label }}: {{ FIELD }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfieldsineed %}
```

(`klass` is a filter I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809874) which returns the class name of the filtered value.)

Unfortunately, `FIELD.label` is only a string. Is there an easy way to render a `<label>` tag for a given form field?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#s-looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Shows you can do

```
{{ FIELD.label_tag }}
```

Should render something like

```
<label for="id_fieldName">Fieldlabel:</label>
```

Comment: I _did_ spend a good twenty minutes reading docs and digging around on the shell with `dir()`. It's easy to miss. DBAD

Comment: how to get it without the `:`? Edit: Sorry, reading helps. The forms `label_suffix` will help you...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been looking for this for over a day now. Do you also know how to access the `id` attribute of the `label_tag`?

Comment: @KareemJeiroudi on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.label_tag
The label_tag method takes an attrs dictionary. I think this might work. I recommend you ask this as a separate question to get a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.ChoiceField(label='Some Foo', ...)
    bar = forms.BooleanField(label='Some Bar', ...)
```

You can render form like:

```
 <div class="col-12">
        <div class="mb-3">
          {{ form.foo.label }}
          {{ form.foo}}
        </div> 
     </div>
```