# Render django widget using template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I really like the ability to use modelforms in django to speed up UI. IE:

```
<html>
    ...
    {{ myform }}
    ...
</html>
```

However, the HTML output I need to create does not match what is created by default. I cannot change my required HTML output, but I would like to change the output of the form.

I know that there are a few approaches to doing so. Looping over the fields and displaying each one individually (i.e. looping and displaying `{{ myform.field }}` ) works ok, but it's not nearly as nice as just doing `{{ myform }}`. Widgets seemed like a good idea, but after looking at the docs & some examples, I am not so sure - I just want to change the html output, not the functionality. If there WAS some way to output a field based perhaps on a template, that would be nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) tag. I create a custom template (form_snippet.html).

For the sake of argument let's say the form_snippet.html just prints the form:

```
<!-- Form snippet -->
{{ form }}
```

Then when you want to use that form template in your other templates you simply have to use:

```
{% include 'form_snippet.html' with form=myform %}
```

You could simply loop over fields and add your custom markup.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. To add to this, I needed to distinguish between different field types - this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809874/get-type-of-django-form-widget-from-within-template/1809982 worked nicely for me.

Comment: Excellent! Something about dead simple template filters makes me smile.