# django templates: How to know form field type and add any buttons based on field type

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am displaying my django forms dynamically with below code.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.field.required %}
        <span class="red">*</span>
    {% endif %}
    {{ field.label }}:
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to know the datatype of fields.if field type is Datetimeinput then I want give one button beside to it to get JavaScript calender.

i want do like as below but I am not able get it

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.field.required %}
        <span class="red">*</span>
    {% endif %}
    {% if field.field_type == 'Datetimeinput' %}
        {{ field.label }}:
        {{ field }}
        <label>From :</label><input type="text" name="from1" class="txtbox"><input type="button" value="Cal" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].from1,'yyyy-mm-dd',this)">
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label }}:
        {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type of Django form widget from within template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809874/get-type-of-django-form-widget-from-within-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom template filter for that.

```
@register.filter
def fieldtype(obj):
    return obj.__class__.__name__
```

Docs on custom filters: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

However, why not just render fields without looping over them?

```
{{ form.birthdate }}
```

Then you'll know for sure what is what.

Comment: Hi Alex & McAbra I don't know Where to write this template filter,in my forms.py or in my models.py, please explain me some more detailed.

Comment: You can create a separate file in your app for custom tags and filters. By the link in my answer you can read on how to register your tags and filters. But do you really need looping? That all looks like an overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Make a template tag. Depending on [Get type of Django form widget from within template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809874/get-type-of-django-form-widget-from-within-template). I used this solution once or twice.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter('klass')
def klass(ob):
    return ob.__class__.__name__
```

In template:

```
{{ field.field.widget|klass }}
```

Will return field class name to be used in your if statements.