# How to check field type in django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm writing a template for django form. I would like to determine the type of field when iterating over all form fields (type attribute inside input tag).

When I write `{{ field }}` it gives me `<input id="id_file" name="file" type="file">` and it's ok, but I would like to override input tag (using bootstrap). Therefore, I need something like `{{ field.type }}` to write `<input name="{{ field.html_name }}" type="{{ field.type}}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="form-control">`

Possible that this can be solved by using filters, but frankly I can not do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the field object through `field`, and from there you'll have access to the `widget` object, which has an `input_type` for inputs:

```
{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}
```

Comment: @ecstaticpeon Thanks. This doesn't seem to work for CheckboxSelectMultiple. I used a custom template filter for it as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1809982/1526703

Answer (score -1):

You can find out using "field.field.widget|widget_type"